# Queue implementation in Swift language

Tags: ios, swift, queue

I m trying to implement Queue collection type in Swift platform. I have got some problems about peek, poll and offer functions. When I try to use these functions in my code, it fails. Do you have any advice or true algorithm for that?

```
import Foundation


class Node<T> {
    var value: T? = nil
    var next: Node<T>? = nil
    var prev: Node<T>? = nil

    init() {
    }

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Queue<T> {

var count: Int = 0

var head: Node<T> = Node<T>()

var tail: Node<T> = Node<T>()

var currentNode : Node<T> = Node<T>()

    init() {
    }

    func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        return self.count == 0
    }

    func next(index:Int) -> T? {

        if isEmpty() {
            return nil
        } else if self.count == 1 {
            var temp: Node<T> = currentNode
            return temp.value
        } else if index == self.count{
            return currentNode.value

        }else {
            var temp: Node<T> = currentNode
            currentNode = currentNode.next!
            return temp.value
        }

    }

    func setCurrentNode(){
        currentNode = head
    }

    func enQueue(key: T) {
        var node = Node<T>(value: key)
        if self.isEmpty() {
            self.head = node
            self.tail = node
        } else {
            node.next = self.head
            self.head.prev = node
            self.head = node
        }

        self.count++
    }

    func deQueue() -> T? {
        if self.isEmpty() {
            return nil
        } else if self.count == 1 {
            var temp: Node<T> = self.tail
            self.count--
            return temp.value
        } else {
            var temp: Node<T> = self.tail
            self.tail = self.tail.prev!
            self.count--
            return temp.value
        }
    }



    //retrieve the top most item
    func peek() -> T? {

        if isEmpty() {
            return nil
        }

        return head.value!
    }

    func poll() -> T? {

        if isEmpty() {
            return nil
        }else{
            var temp:T = head.value!
            deQueue()
            return temp
        }

    }

    func offer(var key:T)->Bool{
        var status:Bool = false;

        self.enQueue(key)
        status = true


        return status
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should be more specific when you say you have *some problems* and *it fails*. Unexpected results, runtime exceptions, ...

Comment: @Antonio you re right. the main problem is about algoritm i think. Especially pop and offer algoritm give nil and application fails. All of them are general exceptions, i couldn't figure it out

Comment: I suggest you to put some breakpoints and spend some time debugging - and I recommend writing some tests, starting from very simple tests (such as testing length for an empty queue) and progressively increasing their complexity.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Aside from the bugs, there are a couple of things about your implementation that you probably want to change to make it more Swift-like.  One is it looks like you're replicating the Java names like `poll` and `offer` – these names are (IMHO) a little strange, and partly related to needing to have two functions, an exception-throwing version and a non-exception version.  Since Swift doesn't have exceptions, you can probably just name them using the conventional names other Swift collections use, like append.

The other issue is that your implementation incorporates traversing the queue into the queue itself.  It's better to do this kind of traversal outside the collection than mix the two.  Swift collections do this with indexes.

Here's a possible Swift-like queue implementation.  First, the node and base queue definition:

```
// singly rather than doubly linked list implementation
// private, as users of Queue never use this directly
private final class QueueNode<T> {
    // note, not optional – every node has a value
    var value: T
    // but the last node doesn't have a next
    var next: QueueNode<T>? = nil

    init(value: T) { self.value = value }
}

// Ideally, Queue would be a struct with value semantics but 
// I'll leave that for now
public final class Queue<T> {
    // note, these are both optionals, to handle
    // an empty queue
    private var head: QueueNode<T>? = nil
    private var tail: QueueNode<T>? = nil

    public init() { }
}
```

Then, extend with an `append` and `dequeue` method:

```
extension Queue {
    // append is the standard name in Swift for this operation
    public func append(newElement: T) {
        let oldTail = tail
        self.tail = QueueNode(value: newElement)
        if  head == nil { head = tail }
        else { oldTail?.next = self.tail }
    }

    public func dequeue() -> T? {
        if let head = self.head {
            self.head = head.next
            if head.next == nil { tail = nil }
            return head.value
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, you're almost done if all you want to do is add and remove.  To add traversal, first create an index type, which is a simple wrapper on the node type:

```
public struct QueueIndex<T>: ForwardIndexType {
    private let node: QueueNode<T>?
    public func successor() -> QueueIndex<T> {
        return QueueIndex(node: node?.next)
    }
}

public func ==<T>(lhs: QueueIndex<T>, rhs: QueueIndex<T>) -> Bool {
    return lhs.node === rhs.node
}
```

Then, use this index to conform to `MutableCollectionType`:

```
extension Queue: MutableCollectionType {
    public typealias Index = QueueIndex<T>
    public var startIndex: Index { return Index(node: head) }
    public var endIndex: Index { return Index(node: nil) }

    public subscript(idx: Index) -> T {
        get {
            precondition(idx.node != nil, "Attempt to subscript out of bounds")
            return idx.node!.value
        }
        set(newValue) {
            precondition(idx.node != nil, "Attempt to subscript out of bounds")
            idx.node!.value = newValue
        }
    }

    typealias Generator = IndexingGenerator<Queue>
    public func generate() -> Generator {
        return Generator(self)
    }
}
```

From conforming to collection type, you get a whole load of stuff for free:

```
var q = Queue<String>()
q.append("one")
q.append("two")

for x in q {
    println(x)
}

isEmpty(q) // returns false
first(q)   // returns Optional("one")
count(q)   // returns 2
",".join(q)  // returns "one,two"
let x = find(q, "two")  // returns index of second entry
let counts = map(q) { count($0) }  // returns [3,3]
```

Finally, there's 3 more protocols that are good to conform to: `ExtensibleCollectionType`, `Printable` and `ArrayLiteralConvertible`:

```
// init() and append() requirements are already covered
extension Queue: ExtensibleCollectionType {
    public func reserveCapacity(n: Index.Distance) {
        // do nothing
    }

    public func extend<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>
      (newElements: S) {
        for x in newElements {
            self.append(x)
        }
    }
}

extension Queue: ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    public convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: T...) {
        self.init()
        // conformance to ExtensibleCollectionType makes this easy
        self.extend(elements)
    }
}

extension Queue: Printable {
    // pretty easy given conformance to CollectionType
    public var description: String {
        return "[" + ", ".join(map(self,toString)) + "]"
    }
}
```

These mean you can now create queues as easily arrays or sets:

```
var q: Queue = [1,2,3]
println(q)  // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: thank you so much.  this is so helpfull. I just try to convert one of my complex academic android project to ios, and i stucked here. so i ll try to implement peek, poll and offer functionality also. Thank you again

Comment: i tried your code, i get segmentation fault on for loop. Do you advice me sth?

Etc: for x in q { } this gives segmentation fault

Comment: Hi Airspeed Velocity, I'm currently using this implementation on our Swift 2.3 project, however, upon migrating to Swift 3.0, ForwardIndexType has been renamed to Comparable. Could you possibly add Swift 3.0 version of this Queue implementation?

Comment: `Use of undeclared type 'Printable'` - anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Would be great, if someone upgraded it to Swift 5+ :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of little issues regarding the internal consistency of your model:

1. When you first instantiate a new `Queue`, you are initializing `head`, `tail` and `current` to three different `Node` objects (even though nothing's been queued yet!). That doesn't make sense. Personally, I'd be inclined to make those three properties optional and leave them as `nil` until you start enqueuing stuff.

   By the way, when you start using optionals for these properties, many of the other methods are simplified.
2. It looks like you're trying to implement a doubly linked list. So, when you dequeue, you need to not only update the `Queue` properties, but you also need to update the `next` pointer for the next item that will be dequeued (because it still will be pointing to that item you already dequeued). You don't want your linked list maintaining references to objects that have been dequeued and should be removed.
3. When you dequeue the last item, you really should be clearing out `head` and `tail` references.
4. You're implementing a doubly linked list, without regard to the object ownership model. Thus, as soon as you have more than one item in your list, you've got a strong reference cycle between nodes and if not remedied, this will leak if there are still objects in the queue when the queue, itself, is deallocated. Consider making one of the references `weak` or `unowned`.
5. I'd suggest keeping this simple (just enqueue and dequeue). The concept of `poll` and `offer` may make sense in terms of an arbitrary linked list, but not in the context of a queue. The implementations of `poll` and `offer` are also incorrect (e.g. `poll` calls `deQueue` which removes the tail, but the object you return is the `head`!), but I presume you'd just remove these functions altogether. Likewise, I do not understand the intent of `current` in the context of a queue.
6. I'd suggest you make `Queue` and `Node` conform to `Printable`. It will simplify your debugging process.

Answer (score 2):

The following is code of a playground consisting of a queue implemented with an array and a queue implemented with nodes. There are substantial performance differences between the two but if you going to be iterating through a queue you might want to use one with an array.

```
import UIKit // for NSDate() used in testing)

// QUEUE WITH ARRAY IMPLEMENTATION (For ease of adaptibility, slow enque, faster deque):

struct QueueArray<T> {
    private var items = [T]()

    mutating func enQueue(item: T) {
        items.append(item)
    }

    mutating func deQueue() -> T? {
        return items.removeFirst()
    }

    func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        return items.isEmpty
    }

    func peek() -> T? {
        return items.first
    }
}

// QUEUE WITH NODE IMPLEMENTATION (For performance, if all you need is a queue this is it):

class QNode<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: QNode?

    init(item:T) {
        value = item
    }
}

struct Queue<T> {
    private var top: QNode<T>!
    private var bottom: QNode<T>!

    init() {
        top = nil
        bottom = nil
    }

    mutating func enQueue(item: T) {

        let newNode:QNode<T> = QNode(item: item)

        if top == nil {
            top = newNode
            bottom = top
            return
        }

        bottom.next = newNode
        bottom = newNode
    }

    mutating func deQueue() -> T? {

        let topItem: T? = top?.value
        if topItem == nil {
            return nil
        }

        if let nextItem = top.next {
            top = nextItem
        } else {
            top = nil
            bottom = nil
        }

        return topItem
    }

    func isEmpty() -> Bool {

        return top == nil ? true : false
    }

    func peek() -> T? {
        return top?.value
    }
}



// QUEUE NODES TEST

let testAmount = 100

var queueNodes = Queue<Int>()

let queueNodesEnqueStart = NSDate()

for i in 0...testAmount {
    queueNodes.enQueue(i)
}

let queueNodesEnqueEnd = NSDate()

while !queueNodes.isEmpty() {
    queueNodes.deQueue()
}

let queueNodesDequeEnd = NSDate()

// QUEUE ARRAY TEST

var queueArray = QueueArray<Int>()

let queueArrayEnqueStart = NSDate()

for i in 0...testAmount {
    queueArray.enQueue(i)
}

let queueArrayEnqueEnd = NSDate()

while !queueArray.isEmpty() {
    queueArray.deQueue()
}

let queueArrayDequeEnd = NSDate()

// QUEUE NODES RESULT:

print("queueEnqueDuration: \(queueNodesEnqueEnd.timeIntervalSinceDate(queueNodesEnqueStart)), Deque: \(queueNodesDequeEnd.timeIntervalSinceDate(queueNodesEnqueEnd))")

// QUEUE ARRAY RESULT:

print("queueArrayEnqueDuration: \(queueArrayEnqueEnd.timeIntervalSinceDate(queueArrayEnqueStart)), Deque: \(queueArrayDequeEnd.timeIntervalSinceDate(queueArrayEnqueEnd))")
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 simple Stack for any type; string, int, array, etc.

```
struct Stack<Element>  {
    var items = [Element]()
    mutating func push(_ item: Element) {
        items.append(item)
    }
    mutating func pop() -> Element {
        return items.removeLast()
    }
    mutating func peek() -> Element {
        return items.last!
    }
    mutating func pushFirst(_ item: Element) {
        items.insert(item, at: 0)
    }
}
```

example with strings:

```
 let names = ["Bob", "Sam", "Sue", "Greg", "Brian", "Dave"]

 //create stack of string type
 var stackOfStrings = Stack<String>()

 //add to bottom of stack
 for stringName in names {
    stackOfStrings.push(stringName)
 }

 //print and remove from stack
 for stringName in names {
    print(stringName)
    stackOfStrings.pop(stringName)
 }

 //add to top of stack
 for stringName in names {
    stackOfStrings.pushFirst(stringName)
 }

 //look at item in stack without pop
 for stringName in names {
    //see what Top item is without remove
    let whatIsTopItem = stackOfStrings.peek(stringName)
    if whatIsTopItem == "Bob" {
      print("Best friend Bob is in town!")
    }
 }

 //stack size
 let stackCount = stackOfStrings.items.count
```

more info here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Comment: Not an answer to the question but an answer to the question I was looking for. Upvote!

Comment: If this is a queue then pop() should be `items.removeFirst()` and peek() should be `items.first!`. Otherwise you have a stack implementation.

Comment: Thats correct queue is FIFO and stack is LIFO. Stack is shown.

Comment: Stacks are not Queues!  If a stack has the functionality to pop from the front, then it could be used as a queue, but likely isn't written to efficiently work that way.

Answer (score 0):

***Queue with Array***

```
struct Queue<T> { 
    private var list = [T]() 

    var isEmpty: Bool { return self.list.isEmpty } 
    var front: T? { return self.list.first } 

    mutating func enqueue(_ item: T) { 
        self.list.append(item) 
    } 

    mutating func dequeue() -> T? { 
        guard self.isEmpty == false else { return nil } 
        return self.list.removeFirst() 
    }
}
```