# Queue implementation - unresolved identifier swift map() and toString

Tags: swift

this is a reference to this question:

[Queue implementation in Swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567711/queue-implementation-in-swift-language)

```
extension Queue: Printable {
    // pretty easy given conformance to CollectionType
    public var description: String {
        return "[" + ", ".join(map(self,toString)) + "]"
    }
}
```

in this above code, `Printable` , `map` and `toString` all throw an `unresolved indentifier` error

I fixed `Printable` by defining a protocol like below:

```
protocol Printable {
    var description: String { get }
}
```

this made the error go away (not sure if I did this correctly) but I have no idea how to resolve `map` or `toString`

I understand that `unresolved identifier` means XCode can't find the specified method/variable but I honestly have no idea if `map`, for example, should be imported or manually written out??

Could someone shed some light on this please and explain why this error is produced?

Comment: No need for your `Printable`. Use `CustomStringConvertible`.

Comment: why is it better?

Comment: CustomStringConvertible is a protocol defined in the Swift Standard library. Are you familiar with the basics of Swift, if not it might help to learn the basics before looking at `map` and other functions.

Comment: The code in the linked question is Swift 1(!) code. You have to convert it to the actual version.

Comment: ah well good to know, thanks for the answers fellas